# Update Post status when post is expire

Tags: sql, wordpress, mysqli, custom-post-type

I want to update post status when a post is expiring.
I have saved expiry date in the WordPress post meta (post_price_plan_expiration_date).
I know how to get an expired post with wp_query,
But I want to use SQL query to update post status.

```
$todayDate = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s'));
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'featured_post',
        'value' => '1',
        'compare' => '=='
    ),
    array(
       'key' => 'post_price_plan_expiration_date',
       'value' => $todayDate,
       'compare' => '<='
    ),
)       
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
print_r($wp_query);
```

This code returns me correct posts which I need, But I need to write the same query in SQL, And run that with wp_schedule_event
Any help???

Answer (score 0):

You can always do the following out of a WP_Query

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $results->request;
```

Which should display the generated SQL Query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already try but this not help.
I want to apply query something like this.
"UPDATE {$wpdb->posts}
   SET post_status = 'trash'
   WHERE (post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish') 
   AND ID not in (select post_id from {$wpdb->postmeta} where meta_key='featured_post' and meta_value='1' )
   AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > %d";